# add ClientTemplate to custom command in kendo grid UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-grid

Here is my kendo grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("paymentGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(p => p.AccountName).Title("Account Name");
      columns.Bound(p => p.Active).Title("Active").ClientTemplate("<div>#=Active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'#</div>");
      columns.Command(command => command.Custom("DeActivate").Click("deActivatePaymentAccount").Text("DeActivate")).Title("DeActivate");
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true).PageSizes(true).Messages(messages => messages.Empty("No accounts found")))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .ServerOperation(false)
      .Model(model =>
      {
        model.Id(p => p.AccountId);
      })
      .Update(update => update.Action("EditAccount", "Account"))
    )
  )
```

Question:
  How do I add a client Template to my Custom Command (Deactivate) so I can toggle the text on the button based on whether the account is active or not?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to change the button text is to do this in the javascript function bound to the click event :

```
    function deActivatePaymentAccount(e) {
        var $btn = $(e.target);
        $btn.text() === "DeActivate" ? $btn.text("Activate") : $btn.text("DeActivate");
        // some other code here
    }
```

Comment: hey Samuel, thanks for your answer - I already did this with the javascript function.  However i wanted to do it like my other bound column Active using a client template.